# Can I make Apple Mail use "m" as the "mark unread" hotkey?

Tags: keyboard, mail.app

I'd like to make "m" the hotkey for marking emails unread, since that's the same key as every other email or RSS application uses, and command+shift+u is unwieldy. The only place I can find to set this is the global hotkeys and it won't let me use unmodified keys (presumably because that would break things). Is it possible to do this?

Comment: In Mail unmodified keys are used to jump to the first mail where the beginning of the Subject line matches the key pressed.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

1. Go to *System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts*
2. click *App Shortcuts* and add a new shortcut using the "+" button
3. Select *Mail* from the list of your applications
4. As *Menu Title*, you have to put the **exact** name of the menu command you want to add. In your case, it should be "*As unread*"
5. Choose the shortcut you want
6. Just *Add* the modification

After these steps, just restart Mail and it's done. You can check on the menu bar to see that the shortcut has been modified.

Comment: Have you tried this yourself? You are not allowed to use unmodified keys in such shortcuts, as the asker has wanted.

Comment: @NetherLinks Of course I tried, and it works for me.

Comment: I cannot get the Shortcuts Panel to accept just "m" or "Shift-M". Please tell how you got that to work.

Comment: Does not work for me with El Capitan, which OS X version are you using @MarcoGiordani?

Comment: @NetherLinks Try to choose cmd + M instead, it should work for you too. Anyway, cmd+shift+u can be modified in this way for sure.